# Boundaries of $\iiint\limits_V \sqrt{x^2+y^2} \,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy \,\mathrm dz$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

How to find out boundaries of triple integrals ? How to switch paraboloid in equation into other coordinates. I've tried to switch into spherical coordinates, but it didn't help, since in the end i couldn't find theta boundaries. The integral is given below:

$$\iiint\limits_V \sqrt{x^2+y^2} \,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy \,\mathrm dz$$

$\bar V = \{ (x,y,z)\in \mathbb R :  z\leq 5- x^2 -y^2, 2z \geq \sqrt {x^2 + y^2},y \geq0\}$

Comment: Those boundaries are made for cylindrical coordinates.

Comment: how would u implement those ?

Comment: ok i got it, thanks for hint :)

Comment: You’re welcome!